# Xcode auto-complete suggests mysterious "songsAtIndexes" for NSArray getter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, nsarray

I have a property of type NSArray on my class called "songs". I'm creating a custom getter for it and XCode gives me an option of creating a method:

```
songsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
```

What is this and why is XCode offering this? Is this specific to NSArray properties? What is the purpose of creating a method/getter for this method? If I don't define it manually, will it be automatically created/synthesized?

Comment: Xcode might just be being clever with combining variable names and trying to figure out what you want to do.

Comment: It's actually a result of KVC: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html, `Or implement the method -countOf<Key> and one or both of -objectIn<Key>AtIndex: or -<key>AtIndexes:.`

Comment: i think that is for KVO/KVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of a little-used KVC optimization for indexed collections which can be used on your class. You can read about this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html), but to excerpt:

> Indexed To-Many Relationship Compliance
>
> For indexed to-many relationships, KVC compliance requires that your class:
>
> - Implement a method named `-<key>` that returns an array.
> - Or have an array instance variable named `<key>` or `_<key>`.
> - Or implement the method `-countOf<Key>` and one or both of -objectInAtIndex: or `-<key>AtIndexes:`.
> - Optionally, you can also implement `-get<Key>:range:` to improve performance.

It's only really used with Core Data with KVC (and occasionally `NSPredicate`s), but you can leverage these methods if you'd like to.

It's really not necessary in 99% of cases to implement this, but you can if you'd like.