# Xcode generates some remove methods for my property, what are they?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I define a property like:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *myTestObject;`

Xcode would automatically generate 4 methods, all begins with "remove":
[image]

So what is this mechanism, and how to use it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it has something to do with KVC (and maybe Core Data?). Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559088/988260) and [Apple's KVC programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Compliant.html).